# how to userinput without typing to a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to run a batch file which requires user input "y/n" to do further action. I want to call this batch file for automation, as during automation argument yes or no need to be passed without user intervention, any idea how to achieve it ?

```
cmd /c setup.bat
```

Now if `setup.bat` is run " yes or no " need to be selected to get the desired result 
as now this `setup.bat` is called during automation. Is there anyway to pass "yes" parameter as an input to `setup.bat`?

Comment: What part of the setup.bat file is being used to request "y/n"?

Answer (score 5):

You can use stream operators like <. Write every expected answer one per line in a file (e.g. foi). Pass this file to the setup.bat using < operator:

```
cmd /c setup.bat < foi
```

Answer (score 4):

Use below command line to automate "yes" answer by simulating `y` key press (will include the `ENTER` key).

```
cmd /c echo y^> "%temp%\answer.tmp" ^& (setup.bat ^< "%temp%\answer.tmp") ^& del "%temp%\answer.tmp"
```

To automate "no" answer by simulating `n` key then ENTER` key.

```
cmd /c echo n^> "%temp%\answer.tmp" ^& (setup.bat ^< "%temp%\answer.tmp") ^& del "%temp%\answer.tmp"
```

To automate "yes" answer by simulating "yes" key presses then `ENTER` key:

```
cmd /c echo yes^> "%temp%\answer.tmp" ^& (setup.bat ^< "%temp%\answer.tmp") ^& del "%temp%\answer.tmp"
```

To automate "no" answer by simulating "no" key presses then `ENTER` key:

```
cmd /c echo no^> "%temp%\answer.tmp" ^& (setup.bat ^< "%temp%\answer.tmp") ^& del "%temp%\answer.tmp"
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simplest solution here is using the pipe with cmd
( | : Reads the output from one command and writes it to the input of another command. Also known as a pipe)
so for you its..

```
cmd /c echo Y | setup.bat
```

where Y will be your prompt input, the pressing of which you wish to automate